# Ubuntu home folder larger than sum of user folders

Tags: ubuntu, home-directory, directory-listing

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.
I don't understand this:

```
>> cd /home

>> sudo du -shc * | sort -hr


13G total
13G myuser

>> ls -a
. .. myuser

>> cd myuser
>> sudo du -shc * | sort -hr
6.4G total
...
```

If myuser is the only folder in /home, why is home 13G but myuser is only 6.4G?

Edit:
The output of df is

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             3924400        4   3924396   1% /dev
tmpfs             787040     1204    785836   1% /run
/dev/sda5      127862492 30653824  90690500  26% /
none                   4        0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
none             3935184      176   3935008   1% /run/shm
none              102400       12    102388   1% /run/user
```

Answer (score 2):

It's an illusion, because `*` doesn't expand to hidden files and directories.

See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1168/108618) for some hints on how to deal with `.*`.

Useful tool: `ncdu`.

Comment: Thanks! It's a bit unintuitive that `*` doesn't expand to include `.*`, your link is very helpful! Doing `.*` gave 13G.

Comment: You could also omit the `*` and `.*` or explicitly use `.`.